# SuperUser retag request: [macosx] -> [mac] + [osx] (diamond mods only!)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

There are [only three `[macosx]` questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macosx) on Super User at this moment.  All of them are closed (migrated from SU to elsewhere), so I can't retag them, nominate them for deletion, or even flag them for moderator attention.

Could a Diamond mod please go through and either

- convert `[macosx]` into `[mac]` and/or `[osx]` where appropriate, or
- just delete the durned things?

<sub>they were all posted and migrated in November, so there's really no need to keep them around...</sub>

[post one](https://superuser.com/questions/66100/how-can-i-fix-xcode-compiling-everything-all-the-time-closed), [post two](https://superuser.com/questions/68408/osx-server-how-to-create-internet-sharing-with-quota-tracking-closed), [post three](https://superuser.com/questions/69160/will-setting-mysql-root-password-prevent-it-from-autostarting-closed)

Answer (score 3):

Done, Done and Done.

Comment: sweeeeeet.  thankee sir.  i'll keep settin' 'em up if you'll keep knockin' 'em down.

Comment: That's what I am here for :)

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X Version 10.5.6 is Leopard (I think), so maybe [Mac] [OSX-Leopard]

Comment: lots of other discussions on what the tags should be on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25559/mac-and-osx-tag-usage-on-su http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39575/merge-tags-macosx-and-mac-os-x-on-so http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/please-could-we-combine-the-osx-and-macosx-tags ... i'm pretty sure we've settled on `[mac]` and `[osx]` (1500+ tags each, IIRC).  if they need more clarity they can get a separate `[leopard]` or `[snow-leopard]` (70 and 350 tags... and two of these already have them).